# How to end a function from executing through timer using javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I made this small, short childish quiz just to practice javascript skills since im a newbie here. This is the code:

```
    <! DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Interactive quiz</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Start the quiz" name="quiz" onclick="durationOfQuiz();">


<script>
var questions = ["How many times did 50 cent get shot? a)9 b)4 c)3", 
"What year did Micheal Jackson die? a)2009 b) 2012 c) 2010",
"How many awards has Drake recieved as of January 2015? a)34 b)36 c) 20",
"What year did Kanye West win his first award? a) 2004 b) 2005 c )2003",
"How old is 50 cent? a)45 b)38 c )39",
"What year did the beatles break up? a)1987 b)1970 c)1966",
"How many sons does 50 cent have? a)4 b)3 c)2",
"When did 2Pac die? a)1996 b)1990 c)1991",
"When did biggie smalls die? a)1997 b)1980 d) 1990",
"when did eazy e die? a)1995 b)1996 c) 1989"];

var userAnswers = [];
var pointCounter = 0;

function durationOfQuiz(){
//TIMER GOES HERE
//gettingAnswers();
setTimeout(gettingAnswers,0);
//ENDING TIMER
}

function gettingAnswers (){

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
var answers = prompt(questions[i]);
userAnswers[i] = answers;
}

if(userAnswers[0] == "9"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[0] == "a"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[1] == "2012"){document.write("<p>" + questions[1] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[1] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[1] == "a"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[1] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[1] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[2] == "36"){document.write("<p>" + questions[2] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[2] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[2] == "b"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[2] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[2] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[3] == "2004"){document.write("<p>" + questions[3] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[3] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[3] == "a"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[3] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[3] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[4] == "39"){document.write("<p>" + questions[4] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[4] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[4] == "c"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[4] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[4] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[5] == "1970"){document.write("<p>" + questions[5] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[5] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[5] == "b"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[5] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[5] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[6] == "2"){document.write("<p>" + questions[6] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[6] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[6] == "c"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[6] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[6] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[7] == "1996"){document.write("<p>" + questions[7] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[7] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[7] == "a"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[7] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[7] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[8] == "1997"){document.write("<p>" + questions[8] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[8] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[8] == "a"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[8] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[8] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[9] == "1995"){document.write("<p>" + questions[9] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[9] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[9] == "a"){document.write("<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>");pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.write("<p>" + questions[9] + " You typed in " +userAnswers[9] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"); pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

document.write("Total point = " + pointCounter);

if(pointCounter<5){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="grey";
}else if(pointCounter > 6 && pointCounter <10){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="pink";
}else if(pointCounter > 11){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
}


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So its pretty much basic but I want to implement a feature where the user has 2 minutes to answer the questions otherwise the quiz finishes. I was thinking I should use a setTimeOut function where I pass the 'gettingAnswers' function in the parameter and set it 0 ms so it executes straight away since I don't want any delays BUT I don't know how to finish the execution of the gettingAnswers function if 2 minutes have passed... I was thinking on clearTimeOut() maybe?

Comment: I think you need to improve your js overall...

Comment: That is not how setTimeout works. It is for executing a function asynchronously after a delay. Setting that delay to 0 results in executing the function at the next tick, ie asynchronously as soon as the browser can.

Comment: Also, using ``prompt`` will suspend your timers until the prompt is closed. So you shouldn't use prompt to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`clearTimeout(timer)` allows to cancel a function call which wasn't yet executed, `timer` being the result of a previous call to `setTimeout`, i.e. `var timer = setTimeout(gettingAnswers, 0);`. So this is not your case.

You should implement a function `finishQuiz();` which you call with a `setTimeout` and `gettingAnswers` should be called without any delay:

```
gettingAnswers();//executed immediately and builds the questions on page
setTimeout(finishQuiz, 2 * 60 * 1000);//executed in 2 minutes and stops quiz
```

Where `finishQuiz` should calculate the score, display it and hide questions. While the user is taking time to answer you shouldn't be executing any functions in my vision.

You question is more about algorithm not about programming technique. Better site for it would be [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)